# DAX Year over Year Change in Cash for different Organizations

Tags: dax, powerbi

I am working in PowerBI and would like to accomplish this issue using DAX. I have a table structured as follows:

```
ID      Year    Cash
3001    1999    1,200
3001    2000    1,000
3001    2001    2,200
3001    2002    1,900
...     ...     ...
8500    2014    3,520
```

I am trying to identify the organizations (indicated by the 'ID' column) that experienced decreases in cash for two consecutive years. There are several thousand organizations, and I have data on every organization from year 1999-2014.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first calculate a column for the Prior year Cash values e.g. for [Cash Year-1] as:

`=LOOKUPVALUE([Cash],[ID],[ID],[Year],[Year] - 1)`

I would repeat for -2.

Then I would use an IF statement to calculate the final column e.g. [Cash Trend]:

`=IF(AND([Cash]<[Cash Year-1],[Cash Year-1]<[Cash Year-2]),"Declining for 2 years","Other")`

Comment: Thank you for your help, Mike. Your recommendation works great!